# Is there a way to add two elements to a single UITableView row

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView that has three rows.  Each cell is created via code as a DataElement as follows:

```
DataElement *e = [[DataElement allc] initFloatWithLabel:@"Price" defaultValue:o format:"@.2f" plcaeholder:@"" unit:@""]

and

e= [[DataElement alloc] initSegmentedControlWithLabel:@"Unit of Sale" defaultValue:0 items:<an array with gallons and liters>]
```

I'll try to duplicate visually what I'm after.

Price ...........[price entry field on right side]

Unit of Sale.....[segmented control for gallons and liters]

Total............[total field based on other cells with number of gals and liters]

Is there a way to place the price and segmented control on the same row?

Price.............[price entry field].....[segmentedcontrol Gals  or Liters]

Total.............[total field]

Coding in Objective C

Comment: You can create a custom table view cell and in the .xib file do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several approaches:

- Use UIStackView to organize your cells (as UIViews) on the screen - for example set up Vertical UIStackView with three rows, and put two UIStackViews into first two rows and one, in the last.
- Use UICollectionView and arrange layout properly

Example is below, please note, this is a top level of set of classes, See https://github.com/pablogsIO/PGMenu/  (Swift prototype)

GMStackMenu.h

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    #import "GMGradient.h"
    #import "UIColor+ColorHex.h"
    
    NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN
    
    @protocol GMStackMenuDelegate <NSObject>
    @optional
    - (void)stackMenuButtonPressedWithTag:(NSInteger) aTag;
    
    @end
    
    /**
        ButtonList Array of arrays:
            @[  @(buttonTag), NSString *imageName, NSString *labelText, CMGradient *gradient ]
     */
    
    
    @interface GMStackMenu : UIView
    
    @property (nonatomic, assign) id <GMStackMenuDelegate> delegate;
    
    - (instancetype) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andButtonList:(NSArray *)bList;
    
    
    - (void) showOnScreen;
    - (void) hideFromScreen;
    
    @end
    
    NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

GMStackMenu.m

```
#import "GMStackMenu.h"
#import "GMButtonMeniItem.h"

#define RELATION_FACTOR     (0.4*6./7.)

#define BUTTONS_PER_ROW     2

@interface GMStackMenu() {
    UIStackView *outer;
}

@end

@implementation GMStackMenu

- (instancetype) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andButtonList:(NSArray *)bList 
{
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        [self stackConfiguration];
        [self stackItemsConfiguration:bList];
        self.alpha = 0.0;
        [self hideFromScreen];
    }
    return self;
}


- (void) stackConfiguration
{
    CGRect stackviewFrame = CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x,
                                       self.frame.origin.y + 100, // отступ сверху
                                       self.frame.size.width,
                                       self.frame.size.height - 100);
    outer = [[UIStackView alloc] initWithFrame: stackviewFrame];

    outer.axis = UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical;
    outer.alignment = UIStackViewAlignmentCenter;
    outer.distribution = UIStackViewDistributionFillEqually;
    outer.spacing = .0;
    outer.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;

    [self addSubview:outer];

     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(buttonClicked:) name: GMCircularButtonTapped object:nil];
}

- (void) stackItemsConfiguration:(NSArray *)bList
{
    BOOL odd = NO;
    NSInteger rows = bList.count / BUTTONS_PER_ROW;
    if (rows * BUTTONS_PER_ROW != bList.count) {
        rows++;
        odd = YES;
    }
//    CGRect containerFrame = self.frame;
//    containerFrame.origin = CGPointZero;
//    UIView *container = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:containerFrame];
    CGFloat leadTrail = (self.frame.size.width - BUTTONS_PER_ROW*(RELATION_FACTOR  * self.frame.size.width))/(BUTTONS_PER_ROW + 1.0);

    CGFloat buttonSize = 0.75 * (self.frame.size.width - leadTrail * 2.0)/ BUTTONS_PER_ROW;
    CGFloat xStep = buttonSize * 0.25;
//    CGFloat yoffset = (self.frame.size.height - buttonSize*rows - xStep*(rows - 1)) / 2.0;
    CGFloat internalWidth = BUTTONS_PER_ROW * buttonSize + xStep*(BUTTONS_PER_ROW - 1);

    CGFloat externalHeight = rows * buttonSize + (rows - 1) * xStep;
    [outer.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:externalHeight].active = true;

    [self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:outer
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:self
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                         multiplier:1.0
                                                           constant:50.0]];


    UIStackView *internalHor = nil;
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < bList.count; i++) {
        NSArray *a = bList[i];
        NSInteger rowOffset = i % BUTTONS_PER_ROW;
        if (rowOffset == 0) {

            internalHor = [[UIStackView alloc] init];
            internalHor.axis = UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal;
            internalHor.alignment = UIStackViewAlignmentCenter;
            internalHor.distribution = UIStackViewDistributionFillEqually;
            internalHor.spacing = xStep;
            internalHor.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
            [internalHor.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:buttonSize].active = true;
            [internalHor.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:internalWidth].active = true;

            [outer addArrangedSubview:internalHor];
        }
 //       NSInteger currentRow = i  / BUTTONS_PER_ROW;
        NSInteger tag = [a[0] integerValue];    // тег кнопки
        NSString *imName = a[1];
        NSString *lblText = a[2];
        GMGradient *gradient = a[3];

//        CGFloat xOffset = leadTrail + rowOffset * (buttonSize + xStep);
//        CGFloat yOffset = yoffset + currentRow  * (buttonSize + xStep);

        CGRect buttonFrame = CGRectMake(0,0,buttonSize, buttonSize);
        GMButtonMeniItem *item = [[GMButtonMeniItem alloc] initWithFrame:buttonFrame imageName:imName
                                                               labelText:lblText gradient:gradient
                                                         andComponentTag:tag];
        [item.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:buttonSize].active = true;
  //      [item.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:buttonSize].active = true;

        [internalHor addArrangedSubview:item];
        
    }
    // добавим блюр
    CGRect frame = self.frame;
    UIBlurEffect *blurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleExtraLight];
    UIVisualEffectView *efView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:blurEffect];
    efView.frame = frame;
    [self insertSubview:efView belowSubview:self.subviews.firstObject];

}




- (void) buttonClicked:(NSNotification *) note
{
    NSInteger bTag = [[note object] integerValue];
    if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(stackMenuButtonPressedWithTag:)]) {
        [self.delegate stackMenuButtonPressedWithTag:bTag];
        [self hideFromScreen];
    }
}


- (void) showOnScreen
{
    CGRect b = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
    CGRect targetFrame = CGRectMake(0, b.origin.y,
                                    b.size.width, b.size.height);
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        self.frame = targetFrame;
        self.alpha = 1.0;
    }];
}

- (void) hideFromScreen
{
    CGRect b = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
    CGRect targetFrame = CGRectMake(b.size.width, b.origin.y,
                                    b.size.width, b.size.height);
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        self.frame = targetFrame;
        self.alpha = 0.0;
    }];

}


@end
```

Comment: Boy, that's a lot of code just to accomplish this simple task.  Thank you for taking the time to show this.

Do you happen to have a UICollection example using Objective-C?